# C# Code searching the assigned values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-macros

I am running into a strange problem with existing code in C# Windows application.
The architecture of the code is in such a way that a single collection contains multiple properties. This gets populated at various places all across various modules -
 Just to explain lets say a property -

```
public Class MyCollection
{
    public list<ClassA> classA {get ; set ;}
    public list<ClassB> classB {get;set;}
    --
    --
    --
    -- this continues up to 20 more properties.
}
```

The instance of this collection is used either to retrieve the values of collections -
     For example getting the values -

```
Public void Function(MyCollection x)
{
    var m= x.ClassA; //Get;
    x.ClassA= function to populate List of ClassA; ( Pseudo code)   
}
```

The problem occurs in finding out all the places in code where this collection is populated. I tried with searching references but it gives me 1000 places where this instance has reference, so this is of no help.
Fortunately the name of instance `x` is same all across. Is there any way or macro which can let me check wherever collection of instance is assigned ?

```
x.ClassA= // - find everywhere. So i am trying to search a wildcard as 
x.___=
```

Any input is deeply appreciated.

Comment: How about using "Find all references" on the property's setter? That's assuming you're using Visual Studio.

Comment: But this one will give all the references not exactly setter.

Comment: It works for me. I right clicked on `set;` and "find all references" and all lines returned were ones where the value was set.

Comment: Thanks George i appreciate your response!